# How to use my Custom AuthorizeAttribute in my view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, authorization

I Create my won Authorize Attribute. Thats work great in the controller.
How can I use it in the view.

Example : I have a manage user link, If you haven't access to this page, I don't want to show the link.

Here is my Authorize Attribute.

```
public class UserAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Session["UserID"] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            IIssUserRepository repUser = new IssUserRepository(EntityFactory.GetEntity());
            IssUser usr = repUser.GetUserByID(Convert.ToInt32(httpContext.Session["UserID"]));

            return usr.CanManageUser;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            if (filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                  new RouteValueDictionary {
                      { "clubShortName", filterContext.RouteData.Values[ "clubShortName" ] },
                      { "area",""},
                      { "controller", "Account" },
                      { "action", "Unauthorized" }
                    });
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is how I use it in the controller:

```
 [UserAuthorize]
 public class UserController : Controller
```

I need to use that in the view. But how

```
<li class="CssMenui">Product</li>
<%if (......... UserAuthorize .......) %>
    <li class="CssMenui">User Management</li>
<li class="CssMenui">Other</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid solution is to add flag to ViewData in your overriding for `OnAuthorization`:

```
var view = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
if (view != null)
   view.ViewData["IsAuthorized"] = !(filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult);
```

and after that your view can be rewritten:

```
  <li class="CssMenui">Product</li>
  <%if (((bool?)ViewData["IsAuthorized"]) == true) %>
      <li class="CssMenui">User Management</li>
  <li class="CssMenui">Other</li>
```

Looks a little dirty for me, but it could help.

Comment: The problem here, is the ViewData["IsAuthorized"] is always empty(null). Just specify that my menu is in a master page. The  [UserAuthorize]
 is never call at this time...

Comment: Sees like Mystery to me, another idea is to create custom controller, derived from Controller, override OnActionExecuting and set ViewData["IsAuthorized"] there, but it's even more dirty((

Comment: Another guess is about caching. Maybe OnAuthorization is skipped, because IIS thinks, than nothing changed.